# Titanium view .add() is not adding a child

Tags: ios, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am currently making a weather forecast application in titanium and within this app I have a container that should display several bars, one for each forecast provider.

The View that the bar views are added to

```
providers = Ti.UI.createView({
  width: '100%',
  height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
  layout: 'vertical'
});
```

The code responsible for removing and adding the bar views to `providers`

```
providers.removeAllChildren();
i = 0;
Ti.API.info("-------- size: " + size + " -------------");
while (size && i < size) {
  pBar = providerBars[i];
  if (DetailsView.checkValue(avgV[i]) || DetailsView.checkValue(topV[i]) || DetailsView.checkValue(angV[i])) {
    Ti.API.info('Inside the loop @ ' + i);
    Ti.API.info('pBar.bar' + pBar.bar);
    Ti.API.info('full bar info: ' + JSON.stringify(pBar.bar));
    providers.add(pBar.bar);
    Ti.API.info('Directly after the add: ' + providers.getChildren());
  }
  i++;
}
Ti.API.info(providers.getChildren());
Ti.API.info('-------------------------');
```

The issue here is that the `providers.add(pBar.bar)` is not doing anything the first time it is called. Giving me the following output

> [INFO] -------- size: 2 ------------- 
>   [INFO] Inside the loop @ 0 
>   [INFO] pBar.bar[object TiUIView]
>   [INFO] full bar info:{"width":"100%","top":2,"horizontalWrap":true,"backgroundGradient":{},"height":17} 
>   [INFO] Directly after the add: 
>   [INFO] Inside the loop @ 1  
>   [INFO]pBar.bar[object TiUIView] 
>   [INFO] full bar info 
>  {"width":"100%","top":2,"horizontalWrap":true,"backgroundGradient":{},"height":17} 
>   [INFO] Directly after the add: [object TiUIView] 
>   [INFO] ( "[objectTiUIView]" ) 
>   [INFO] -------------------------

The loop obviously runs two times and `pBar.bar` is a `TiUIView` object, the `providers.add()` is apparently not doing it's job.

Using `Titanium 3.5.1.GA`

I have not run into this issue when building for android, only for iOS so far.

Comment: are you sure `providerBars` array is filled with 2 elements? Also, try `providers.add(providerBars[i].bar)`

Comment: Also it would be good to see the full loop. could you provide a gist? Also I would recommend moving to the latest version of Titanium. 3.5.1.GA is no longer supported.

Comment: Are you recreating the views in `providerBars` each time you loop it? Because if they are already added to another view they won't be addable to other views anymore.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of assumption that need to be made based on the limited code provided.  My immediate reaction is to look at the layout of the container, "providers", that children are being added to.  If this is the default, composite/absolute, and both have a top of 2 as shown, they could be overlaying each other.

Comment: I edited the original post and added the code for creating `providers`. But regardless if both children were added and displayed ontop of each other, the `getChildren()` method should still return a list containing both views